# Is it possible to setup multiple Virtual Hosts with one ip/domain?

Tags: server, apache2, dns, virtualhost

Is it possible to setup multiple Virtual Hosts with one ip/domain?

We have a single domain (example.com) pointing to our server at ip (123.123.555.555). At location 123.123.555.555 we require the following folder structure:

```
# production level
/htdocs/www/prod/proj1/
/htdocs/www/prod/proj2/

# dev level
/htdocs/www/dev/proj3/
/htdocs/www/dev/proj4
```

Where ideally we would like `example.com` to resolve to `/htdocs/www/prod/` and `example.com/dev` to resolve to `/htdocs/www/dev/`.

Simple enough no?

**Caveats:**

1. `dev` and `prod` need different setup directory/apache rules (`allow deny from`, etc)
2. `prod` needs to resolve without `prod` in the url. `example.com/proj1` would goto `example.com/prod/proj1`

**Attempts so far..**

I've tried setting up with the same virtual host, but giving a directory an alias of `/` sends it into a fit, claiming that it will be overwritten later. It makes sense because `/` matches `/` but also `/dev`

I've also tried setting up multiple virtual hosts with apache2' sites-available/sites-enabled but it seems I can't distinguish it based on the ip/domain. Normally I would attempt something like `<Directory 'sub.domain.com'>` and `<Directory 'sub2.domain.com'>`

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

1. Setup a virtualhost for a subdomain of example.com and direct it to your dev folder. Here's an example of a .conf file to put in sites-available:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/htdocs/www/dev/proj3/"
   ServerName dev.example.com
   <Directory "/htdocs/www/dev/proj3/">
   allow from all
   Options +Indexes
   </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Setup virtualhost for a different port, i.e. 8080 or whatever you choose, and point this to the dev folder.

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:8080>
   DocumentRoot "/htdocs/www/dev/proj3/"
   ServerName example.com
   <Directory "/htdocs/www/dev/proj3/">
   allow from all
   Options +Indexes
   </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```