# Different address for each project LAMP

Tags: networking, server, apache2, internet, lamp

I have perfectly working LAMP on my ubuntu 14.04 as well as 16.04,
What I want to do is to access my computer (all web projects of html dir) from internet.
The another thing is that how can I give all project a different name.

For e.g. I have four ex proj_1,proj_2,pro_3,proj_4,

if i type url www.proj_1.com from any device, it should redirect me to my proj_1 and run that project, if type www.proj_2.com redirect to proj_2 dir.

I read many ideas but no one I understand.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/403694/423684) helps you

Comment: Sorry I din't understand that.

Comment: well what it mainly says is that it is possible to map different sites like proj1.example.com, proj2.example.com to different folders on your Server.
For that you have to configure your /etc/apache2/sites_available/something.config

Comment: You need to buy four domain names, or at least one and use subdomains like @derHugo says. Please check [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/a/900594/566421) and [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/a/811416/566421) answers.